# How can i turn on GPS automatically as my android application launches in Ice cream sandwhich

Tags: android, gps

I want to make an android application which can automatically turn on GPS as it is launched. I am having Ice cream sandwhich.please help me

Comment: You can't and you shouldn't - it's ethically questionable to override something the user has set that has security/privacy considerations.

Answer (score 6):

You can't on unrooted device.

Your best option is to show a dialog to user and ask him to turn on those settings (one button might start intent to forward user to location settings).

Comment: Yep, the best proof of this is that Google's navigation app does the same thing.